# Использование Combobox в WPF DataGrid со связью по внешнему ключу

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, sql-server

Здравствуйте.
Возникла задача написать приложение для типичного учета продукции. Выбрал MSSQL, WPF, Entity Framework. В данном случае у меня есть таблица, которая отображается в DataGrid и другие таблицы связанные с ней, как таблицы справочники (*Например:* Таблица "Категория металла", "ФИО" и .т.д.).
Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как мне **правильно** заполнить ComboBox и при выборе элемента соседняя колонка заполнялась бы массой этого элемента взятой из этой таблицы.

*Пример:*

[image]

Привожу исходник моделей:

```
//таблица Stelug - справочник стелюг
public partial class Stelug
    {
        public Stelug()
        {
            this.plavkas = new HashSet<plavka>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public int nStelug { get; set; }
        public double mass { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<plavka> plavkas { get; set; }
    }

//таблицы Plavka - основная таблица где вся информация
public partial class plavka
    {
        public plavka()
        {
            this.chemicals = new HashSet<chemical>();
            this.paketPlavkas = new HashSet<paketPlavka>();
        }

        public System.Guid id { get; set; }
        public int plavka1 { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime dataPrig { get; set; }
        public int catMetal { get; set; }  //это связаное поле с таблицой catMetal
        public Nullable<int> smena { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> masterFIO { get; set; }  //это связаное поле с таблицой FioDict
        public Nullable<int> nSteluga { get; set; } //это связаное поле с таблицой Stelug
        public Nullable<double> mBrutto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> mNetto { get; set; }     
        public Nullable<int> nKonveera { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> otkFIO { get; set; }
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public bool brak { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> mBrak { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }

        public virtual catMetal catMetal1 { get; set; }      
        public virtual FioDict FioDict { get; set; }      
        public virtual ICollection<paketPlavka> paketPlavkas { get; set; }
        public virtual Stelug Stelug { get; set; }
    }
```

Ну а дальше я сделал класс где описал связь с EF:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Наш контекст данных
        /// </summary>
        private MagnesiumEntities _dataContext;

        /// <summary>
        /// таблица "Плавок"
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<plavka> Plavkas { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> CatMetals { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> FioDict { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<Stelug> Stelug { get; private set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _dataContext = new MagnesiumEntities();
            Plavkas = new ObservableCollection<plavka>(_dataContext.plavkas);

            CatMetals = (from db in _dataContext.catMetals select db.category).ToList();
            FioDict = (from db in _dataContext.FioDicts select db.FIO).ToList();
            Stelug = (from db in _dataContext.Stelugs select db).ToList();

            Save = new ActionCommand(SaveChanges) { IsExecutable = true };
        }

        private void SaveChanges()
        {
            _dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        #region Команды

        /// <summary>
        /// Команда для сохранения
        /// </summary>
        public ActionCommand Save { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged 

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы связать запись справочника  FioDicts с свойством masterFIO сущности plavka слудет:
Во-первых: Выбирать записи справочника вместе с идентификаторами

```
FioDict = (from db in _dataContext.FioDicts select new {db.Id, db.FIO}).ToList()
```

Не проверял, но, кажется, для этого не обязательно создавать новый класс. Достаточно и анонимного. Соответственно коллекция будет содержать не string а object.

```
public IEnumerable<object> FioDict { get; private set; }
```

Во-вторых: Колонка таблицы будет связываться с словарем как источником (ItemSource), должно быть указано отображаемое поле анонимного класса (DisplayMemberPath), связываемое свойство выбранного анонимного класса (SelectedValuePath) и связываемое поле редактируемой записи таблицы (SelectedValueBinding). Итого:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ФИО" ItemSource="{Binding FioDict}" DisplayMemberPath="FIO" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
```

Аналогично и остальные колонки.

**Upd1**

Выше описана возможность связывания по Id. При этом информацию в соседнюю ячейку выводить не получится. 
Теперь рассмотрим случай, когда плавка связывается со стелюгой. Здесь используем связь не по Id, а просто привязку сущности.
Обычно при указании связей создаются три свойства:

1. StelugId - внешний ключ
2. Stelug - ссылка на сущность
3. StelugReference - объект вычисляющий по StelugId ссылку на сущность, если она есть в контексте.

Попросим также проводить связывание как только свойство изменится пользователем (UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged):

```
Stelugs = (from db in _dataContext.Stelugs select db).ToList();
```

Разметка колонки

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Стелюга" ItemSource="{Binding Stelugs }" DisplayMemberPath="nStelug" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Stelug, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

В соседней ячейке отобразим массу стелюги:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Масса" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Stelug.mass}" />
```

Теперь самое интересно. Текстовая колонка не знает, что мы указали стелюгу. Поэтому свойство не обновляется автоматически. Дело в том, что в EF устанавливается автоматическое оповещение о примитивных свойствах, но не о связях. Требуется оповестить систему, что свойство изменилось. Сделать это можно в partial-классе стелюги реализовав один из частичных методов (в данном случае, как я упомянул выше, изменяется примитивное свойство Id, поэтому и метод будем использовать соответствующий):

```
public partial class plavka
    {
        partial void OnStelugIdChanged()
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Stelug");
         }
   }
```

Теперь в соседней ячейке будет отображаться свойство выбранной сущности, как только она была выбрана.

Comment: Всё разобрался сделал так:
<wtool:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Номер стелюги" x:Name="stel_cmbx" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="nStelug" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Stelug}" />                    

а в коде делаю так :
stel_cmbx.ItemsSource = _view.Stelug;

Comment: @Пандакун, К чему делать viewmodel, если заполнять списки приходится в коде окна?