# C# WPF Как правильно привязать Combo box к сущности?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq2sql

В комментариях привёл ссылку,где отвечают на мой вопрос,но я не понимаю как он привязывает выбранную сущность в combobox к нужной сущности(Stelug к plavka),а там спросить не могу - репы не хватает.

Программа на C# WPF паттерн MVVM.
Есть сущность detail и employee(LinqTOSQL) и они связаны.
Хочу в datagrid выводить detail и в отдельной колонке работников в виде combobox(DataGridComboBoxColumn),чтобы их можно было менять для этой сущности.
Нашел вроде, сделал подобно http://www.sql.ru/forum/1169706/ne-bindyatsya-dannye-k-combobox-v-wpf-datagrid

ComboBox появился и данные тоже, но при изменении элемента он становится красным(исключение судя по-всему) и не привязывается к сущности(потому что я не привязал, а как не понимаю). Наверняка нужно это прописать в одном из свойств. Но в каком?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу код той самой колонки

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                                DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
                                SelectedValuePath="idemployee"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding employee}" 
                        Header="ФИО отв.лица">
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.GetEmployee}"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.GetEmployee}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Привожу код VM

```
public class DetailVM:ViewModelBase
{
    private TechDepDBDataContext _techDepDB;
    public DetailVM(TechDepDBDataContext db)
    {
        this._techDepDB = db;
        _details = new ObservableCollection<detail>() { new detail { NameDetail = "ara", CountDetail = 2 } };

    }

    public string EssenceName { get { return "Деталь"; } }

    //public DTG_Detail UEdtg
    //{
    //get {return _uedtg;}
    //    set { _uedtg = value; }
    //}

    #region Read/Update
    private List<officememo> _officememo;
    public List<officememo> Select
    {
        get
        {
            _officememo = (from c in _techDepDB.officememo
                          select c).ToList();

            return _officememo;

        }
    }
    #endregion

    public List<employee> GetEmployee
    {
        get 
        {
            var emp= (from c in _techDepDB.employee
                          select c).ToList();
        return emp;
        }
    }

    #region Create
    private ObservableCollection<detail> _details;
    public ObservableCollection<detail> InsertDetailCol
    {
        get
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("_details");
            return _details;

        }
    }


    public void Insert()
    {
        _techDepDB.detail.InsertAllOnSubmit(_details);
        _details.Clear();
        _techDepDB.SubmitChanges();


    }
    #endregion
}
```

Код главной VM
    public class MainVM:ViewModelBase
    {
        private TechDepDBDataContext _db;
        ObservableCollection _pages;

```
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Pages
    {
        get { return _pages; }
        set { _pages = value; }
    }

    public MainVM()
    {_db=new TechDepDBDataContext();
    _db.LoadOptions = GetLoadOption();
        _pages = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
        _pages.Add(new DetailVM(_db));
        _pages.Add(new OperationVM(_db));
        _pages.Add(new OfficeMemoVM(_db));
        _pages.Add(new DeviceVM(_db));
        _pages.Add(new ProjectVM(_db));
    }
```

XAML разметка MainView

```
<Window x:Class="TechDepCRM.MainView"
    x:Name="MainV"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainView" Height="535" Width="778"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:TechDepCRM.ViewModels"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:TechDepCRM.Views"

    DataContext="{Binding MainVM,ElementName=MainV}">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:DetailVM}">
    <view:DetailView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:OperationVM}">
        <view:OperationView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:OfficeMemoVM}">
        <view:OfficeMemoView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:DeviceVM}">
        <view:DeviceView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ProjectVM}">
                  <view:ProjectView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl Name="Tabs" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" Margin="10,36,0,0">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding EssenceName}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

**UPDATE 16.09.16**

Тег DataGrid

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=CBOfficeMemo, Path=SelectedItem.detail}"
```

ComboBox к которому привязывается DataGrid(под "Фильтр" на форме)

```
<ComboBox Name="CBOfficeMemo" ItemsSource="{Binding Select}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="19">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumOfficeMemo}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="\"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding YearOfficeMemo}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: В чем минус? Если часто обсуждалось, прошу кинуть в меня ссылкой.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в ItemsSourse мы засовываем наших работников, а в SelectedValuePath и SelectedValueBinding  биндим как раз по связи к сущности detail?(detail.employee)

Comment: Нашел похожий вопрос [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298651/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-combobox-%D0%B2-wpf-datagrid-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%83?rq=1]
Это мой случай, но я не понимаю как он делает привязку к сущности и через что.

Comment: Вы вообще не должны привязываться к сущностям. Сущности — это модель, а привязываться надо к VM.

Comment: @VladD Да, конечно я привязываюсь VM(добавил в вопрос). Но позже я по сути оперирую сущностями, который получаю через свойство в VM(возникло смутное сомнение, что я не то что-то делаю). И потом в Combobox меняю у той сущности работника. Не так?

Comment: Попробую воспроизвести вашу проблему на домашнем компьютере.

Comment: А вы не могли бы привести больше кода? А то, например, непонятно, что такое GetEmployee и откуда оно берётся.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо. Сейчас нет под рукой компа, но GetEmployee находиться в этой же VM и простым похожим запросом забирает всех работников.

Comment: @VladD Добавил по максимум информацию. По сути больше ничего, кроме .dbml, там нет.

Comment: Окей, сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: Всё равно ничего не ясно. Вы приводите много деталей, но я так и не смог понять, какой же ItemsSource у вашего DataGrid?

Comment: @VladD На форме есть фильтр(на самом деле он пока не совсем даже фильтр). В Combo box фильтра засовываю Select свойство,а от его selected item делаю привязку к data grid(Selected item.detail)

Comment: @VladD добавил код itemsSource DataGrid и ComboBox, к которому привязывается. Это ужасно, но пока так.

Comment: Ну смотрите. У вас в `DataGridComboBoxColumn` написано: `<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.GetEmployee}"/>` (кстати, зачем через стиль, а не прямо? ItemsSource есть и у DataGridComboBoxColumn). А теперь мне нужно откопать из вашего кода, чему у вас равен `DataContext` у `DataGrid` и есть ли у него свойство `GetEmployee`. Вы написали `<DataGrid  ItemsSource=...`, окей, `ItemsSource` нашлось, а какой у него `DataContext`, приходится лишь догадываться.

Comment: Я пытался нормально, но получилось только так.(из примера взял).Я его не задавал явно(DataContext), тобишь(насколько помню) равен DataContext формы.

Comment: Ну, по вашему плану он же каким-то должен быть, раз вы к нему привязываетесь? Если вы его не задали, значит он унаследован от внешних элементов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45480/discussion-between-arantler-and-vladd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы (предыстория в чатике). Спасибо VladD.

Поклацав интерфейс, я внимательно изучил Output и наткнулся на странную строчку:

```
"System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '10' from type 'Int32' to type 'TechDepCRM.employee' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter не может выполнить преобразование из System.Int32."
```

Появилось это при выборе employee и выхода со строчки/клетки

Возник вопрос "Где происходит преобразование?".

Узнал в цифре 10 идентификатор работника моего.

"Где я вообще работаю с идентификатором?"

Вот в этой строчке
SelectedValuePath="idemployee"
Из прочитанного мною ранее(блин) можно сказать, что через это свойство мы видим обращение к элементу ComboBox(не совсем понял, но советовали использовать это для работы с элементами через id)
В итоге сначала пытаясь изменить значение на Entity,employee.
Полностью ее убрал и все заработало.
В бд все записывается.

## Ответ

Уберите строчку **`SelectedValuePath`** или используйте ее грамотно